# Cloudera "service cloudera-scm-agent status/start/stop" returns no result

Tags: ubuntu, cloudera

I am facing very strange error on cloudera i have 23 nodes of cloudera cluster, everything is running fine except one node call it nodeZ it is not communicating with cloudera manager when i am executing command

```
 sudo service cloudera-scm-agent status
```

it returns nothing i tried hard_restart with confirmed but still no result event tried running it from */etc/init.d/* but same thing over there as well.

I looked into logs no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make a copy of your `/etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini`.
- Uninstall the `cloudera-manager-agent` package
- Install the `cloudera-manager-agent` package
- Copy the `/etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini` back
- Start the `cloudera-scm-agent` service

If that doesn't work and the logs don't tell anything interesting, check disk usage, check to ensure that the disk to which `/var/run` is mounted is writable and accessible.

Still doesn't work... try rebooting as a last resort.